# KafkaConsumerAPI - Connect from eclipse to broker running in vm through vagrant

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

What is **advertised.listeners**.  How does it will help to connect to Kafka broker running in a VM from Eclipse?

I have written KafkaConsumer code and tested it with a service running locally. I am trying to use the same code to connect to Kafka Broker running in VM, but records are not getting consumed. Please explain the necessary configuration to achieve the result.

```
package kafkaExample;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRebalanceListener;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.PartitionInfo;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Consumer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    final List<PartitionInfo> partitionInfos;


    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, args[0]);
    /*    props.put("zookeeper.connect", "10.30.3.2:2181,10.30.3.3:2181");*/
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "cgrp1");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "consumer-tutorial");


    final KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(args[1]),
        new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
          @Override
          public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> arg0) {

        }

          @Override
          public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> tps) {

        }
        });

    System.out.println("list of topics " + kafkaConsumer.listTopics());

    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = null;
    while (true) {
      records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
      if (records == null || records.count() == 0) {
        System.out.println("There is no message. try again.");
        continue;
      }

      final Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> iter = records.iterator();
      while (iter.hasNext()) {
        final ConsumerRecord<String, String> cr = iter.next();
        System.out.println("Consume msg: " + cr.value());
      }
      kafkaConsumer.commitSync();
      kafkaConsumer.close();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The advertised listeners will tell your clients to connect to a different address than the primary one of the server itself.

For example, your VM has at least three interfaces, localhost, the internal VM subnet for communication across multiple VMs, then maybe also another for your external host to reach into that VM.

The third could not be there, and if not, then you'd need to setup port forwarding from the host to the VM's internal interface. In that case of a port forward from your host 9092 (could be any number) to the Kafka server 9092, then you'd set the advertised listeners to `PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092` (or the number chosen from the host) and you'd make you application on the host then connect to `127.0.0.1:9092`, and not the VM address

If you had a cluster of VMs on one host, you'd have to use different ports when forwarding, like `127.0.0.1:9092,127.0.0.1:9093`

Comment: I am using vagrant to setup cluster.   For each VM, I am configuring a private network. I am trying to implement 2 node kafka cluster. For example, one kafka server will be running in private IP 10.30.3.30 port: 9092 and another one in IP 10.30.3.20 port:9092. Should I port forward first VM kafka server port to host 9092 and second VM kafka server port to host 9093? Then on one node, advertised listeners needs to be set to  PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092 and another node to  PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9093?